# jade inheritance vs conditionals

Tags: inheritance, pug, conditional-statements

Is it better to use jade's inheritance rather that using conditionals and includes?

The thing is that by using inheritance, jade can be used as if it was logic-less (Like mustache) right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use inheritance for strong differences handling such as the different pages of your site.

You should use conditionnals for small specific things such as 'user is logged ? display name || display link to login page

Comment: Merci Arnaud :)  What is this answer based on? Are there any code standards that dictate this? :)

Comment: The answer is based on common programming practice: use tools sized based on your problem or better said "don't use a big tool for a small problem (include for a simple 'if').

One good way to solve this is comparing the amount (instructions) of code used to solve your problem and how this amount of code will grow has you add functionalities.